# how to use babel decorators for mobx in project generated by create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, mobx-react

I created a project `create-react-app` and installed **mobx**, and **mobx-react**
modules when I use this simple state class in my project I always got this error below.

```
import {autorun, observable} from 'mobx'

export default class AppState{
    @observable teams =[]

    @computed addNewTeam(){
        this.teams.push('Team 1')
    }
}

autorun(()=>{
    console.log(this.teams[0]);
})
```

[image]

Also installed Babel with [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react) guide

how can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 possible solution for me, one is [here](https://github.com/mobxjs/create-react-app-mobx); using mobx without decorators and babeljs transpiler.

second and more close to my need is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-react-scripts); starter kit which using custom react scripts including babeljs config